# Does PokeAPI contain data for every Pokemon generation?

Tags: pokeapi

I am trying to impleement PokeAPI's data for a webapp, but I cannot seem to find all the data I need. When calling some data for, say, butterfree, I would call the data with (https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/butterfree/). Under "stats" it has all 6 of butterfree's stats, however it only has the stats from the most recent generation. Is there a way to specify a specific generation somewhere in the API request URL that would show the stats for a generation before the most recent one?

Comment: i'm running into the same problem. Cannot get the special stat from GEN 1

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @tim-bentley? Having the same problem.

Comment: PokeAPI has explicitly stated that they will not add stats from previous generations. I created a scraper to get this data from Bulbapedia instead

Answer (score 0):

It says on their website that not all information is guaranteed as completely up to date and accurate.

[image: Website Notice]

However, you can update this information yourself or file an issue to report missing/incorrect data in [the pokedex GitHub repo](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokedex/issues).

Comment: That warning was for Sword and Shield (Generation 8), I am trying to get data for older generations, so I'm not sure that that warning is regarding my problem. Thank you for your help!